# Moq : Return null from a mocked method with nullable type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, .net-6.0

I have an implicit operator in an abstract class that is similar to below which converts the data to provided type.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    private object dataHolder; // just for representation
    // at implementation it tries to convert dataHolder object
    // or returns null if failed
    public abstract T? Convert<T>();
    public static implicit operator byte[]?(MyClass obj) => obj.Convert<byte[]?>();
}
```

I am trying to create unit tests for this class

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    Mock<MyClass> mockedClass = new() { CallBase = true };
    mockedClass.Setup(x => x.Convert<byte[]?>()); // no return statement
    // this should be null using implicit operator
    byte[]? output = mockedClass.Object;

    // however I am receiving an empty byte[] (length 0).
    Assert.IsNull(output);
}
```

How do I verify that my output can also be null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test that the implicit operator works as expected you could just verify that the expected underlying method was called.

Something like this;

```
[Test]
public void VerifyThatImplicitOperatorWorksAsExpected()
{
    Mock<MyClass> mockedClass = new() { CallBase = true };
    mockedClass.Setup(x => x.Convert<byte[]?>()).Returns<byte[]?>(null);
    byte[]? output = mockedClass.Object;

    Assert.IsNull(output);
    // Verify that the Convert method was called.
    mockedClass.Verify(x => x.Convert<byte[]?>(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: I believe the implementation I am testing is the implicit operator. For this I need to mock out Convert method, which I would imagine is a valid scenario? Thing that may not be obvious here is while I am returning obj.Convert<T>() in example for simplicity, I may very well be doing some other guards, like null checks/type checks etc which is an implementation I should be testing right?

Comment: Ok, got it. I updated my answer! If you provide more sample code in the implicit operator I can elaborate (as I think other asserts would depend on the situation).

Comment: Thanks for update, but this does not assert that the returned value is null, which is what I am trying to assert. In example this may be used to verify implicit operator but this is very applicable to any method that calls Convert<T>() internally. I could very well be calling the convert method from some other method and attempt to mock out Convert<T>(). Conversion may use complex logic that I don't wish to run/setup for testing every single caller? Hence simpler to mock out the Convert but depend on its known output as null or value (value part I am able to test)?

Comment: This question is about how do I return null value from mocked Method<byte[]?>(). This can be a universal use-case and not specific to operator. Basically any method that takes in byte[]? as type, and can return a nullable return. I want to test the flow when such a method returns null value.

Comment: What you're doing right now is just verifying the moq setup which is pointless.  The only thing you can verify right now is that the expected method is called. Sounds like you're about to introduce some more logic to the operator. If you provide a small example of this logic I think you can get more of the answer you're after.

Comment: To return null you can `mockedClass.Setup(x => x.Convert<byte[]?>()).Returns((byte[])null)`.